# Delete user endpoint using Fetch

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, ejs

I am building a user website, where the admin should be able to delete users.
My project is build using Azure SQL database.
I have in my controllers file, come up with an endpoint deleteUser

#### deleteUser

```
const deleteUser = (req, res) => {
  sql.connect(config, function (err) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    // create Request object
    var request = new sql.Request();
    // query to the database and get the records

    const { id } = req.query

    request.query(
      `DELETE FROM users where User_ID = '${id}'`,
      function (err, recordset) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
        } else if (!id) {
          res.json("Please provide an ID")
        } else {
          res.json(`User with ID: ${id} has been deleted!`)
        }
      }
    );
  });
};
```

I am then trying to make a call to this endpoint using fetch and EJS.

#### My code in EJS script tag

```
<script>

document.getElementById('deleteUserBtn').addEventListener('submit', (e) => {

    e.preventDefault();

    fetch('http://localhost:3000/deleteUser', {
    method:'DELETE',
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: null
    })
    .then((response) => console.log(response))
    .catch((e) => {
        console.log(e)
    })
})
</script>
```

I console log the response, so the route must be good, but it seems as it doesn't parse the ID into the fetch. What is the right way to approach this?

Thanks in advance!

### Solution

I have come up with follow solution - which is not the best, but works.

```js
document.getElementById('deleteUserBtn').addEventListener('submit', (e) => {

    e.preventDefault();

    // delete user using fetch

    const id = document.getElementById('userId').textContent

    fetch(`http://localhost:3000/deleteUser?id=${id}`, {
    method:'DELETE',
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: null
    })
    .then((response) => console.log(response))
    .catch((e) => {
        console.log(e)
    })
})
```

Thanks for the contribution!

Comment: In the fetch you are deleting with body set to null without a query string either? How will the endpoint parse an ID from that?

Comment: should you be appending the userId in the fetch URL? http://.../deleteUser?id={Id}

Comment: @SeanLawton well, the endpoint tries to take the ID from the query. Which is also not present in the request.

Comment: Note that your current code is open to SQL-injection. What if a malicious user decide to set the contents of `document.getElementById('userId')` to `0'%3BDROP+TABLE+users%3B'`? When decoded and parsed on the server will result in an `id` of `"0';DROP TABLE users;'"`, which turns the query into `DELETE FROM users where User_ID = '0';DROP TABLE users;''`.

Answer (score 0):

Should the id not be in the URL of the fetch request? You are asking for the id from the request params, so it should probably be appended to the path like

```
const id = wherever your id comes from; 

fetch('http://localhost:3000/deleteUser?id=${id}...'
```

You'll need to get the user's id in your button method as well, but would need more of your code to see where that comes from.

Comment: The id comes from the following code 

`const editUser = (req, res) => {
  sql.connect(config, function (err) {
    if (err) console.log(err);


    var request = new sql.Request();
    const id = req.params.id;

    request.query(
      `select * from users where User_ID  = '${id}'`,
      function (err, recordset) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
        } else {
          res.render("editUser", { users: recordset.recordsets[0]});
        }
      }
    );
  });
}`
 - Im not sure how to pass it into the script tag

Comment: I can access the users property with following code in my ejs body `<% users.map(user => { %>` however this is not accessible  in the script tag.

Comment: You need to pass the ID as a query string parameter in the URL. The server side that you posted parses the ?id=id from the URL and uses that to delete the specific user.

Answer (score 0):

Usually using an ID for deletion is best approach

```
fetch('http://localhost:3000/deleteUser/:id...'
```

However, you can pass id in anyway in body, params, query or even headers)